# Bitmap issue - parameter is not valid & out of memory

Tags: exception, graphics, parameters, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have a vb.net program that tries to take a bunch of images and change the resolution to a smaller size.  My program tries to loop through all the images to accomplish this using this code below.  I've posted both the function and the button click that calls it.  It will go through 27 images fine but on the 28th will error out with "parameter is not valid".

```
     Friend Shared Function SetResolution(ByVal sourceImage As Image, ByVal resolution As Integer, ByVal strFullPath As String) As Image
    Try
        Dim reduction As Double = resolution / CInt(sourceImage.HorizontalResolution)
        Using newImage As New Bitmap(sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height, sourceImage.PixelFormat)
            newImage.SetResolution(resolution, resolution)
            Dim outImage As New Bitmap(sourceImage, CInt(sourceImage.Width * reduction), CInt(sourceImage.Height * reduction))
            Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
                g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
                g.DrawImage(outImage, 0, 0)
                g.Dispose()

            End Using

            newImage.Dispose()

            Return outImage
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An error occurred with the SetResolution function - " & ex.Message)

    End Try


End Function


 Private Sub btnSaveImages_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveImages.Click

    Dim S As String
    Dim Box As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Any previous images saved to this location will be overwritten.  Are you sure you want to save these images?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
    Dim strFolderPath As String = ""
    Dim strFolderReportPath As String = txtBrowse.Text & "\Report"

    'Try

    'the Report folder may not exist.  Create it if needed.
    If Not Directory.Exists(strFolderReportPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(strFolderReportPath)


    Else
        'if it does exist then we need to either delete the folder or clean out all the files.
        Dim downloadedMessageInfo As System.IO.DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(strFolderReportPath)



        For Each file As FileInfo In downloadedMessageInfo.GetFiles()
            file.Delete()
        Next
        For Each dir As DirectoryInfo In downloadedMessageInfo.GetDirectories()
            dir.Delete(True)
        Next

    End If



    If Box = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

        If lstSelectedImages.Items.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each S In lstSelectedImages.Items
                'MessageBox.Show(S)

                Dim image1 As Image = Image.FromFile(S)
                Dim strFilePath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(S)
                strFolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(S)
                Dim strFileName As String = Path.GetFileName(S)
                Dim strNewFolder As String = strFilePath & "\Report\"

                strFileName = strFileName.Replace(".", "-Report.")

                Dim strFullPath As String = strFilePath & "\Report\" & strFileName

                image1 = SetResolution(image1, 50, strFilePath & "\" & Path.GetFileName(S))

                'the Report folder may not exist.  Create it if needed
                If Not Directory.Exists(strNewFolder) Then
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(strNewFolder)
                End If


                image1.Save(strFullPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                image1.Dispose()
                image1 = Nothing


            Next

            Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(strFolderReportPath)

            'PopulateReportViewer(lstSelectedImages)
            PopulateReportViewerByDir(di)

            lblImageFolderLocation.Text = "Image Location: " & strFolderReportPath

            MsgBox("Images saved to " & strFolderReportPath)

        Else

            MsgBox("Please select images to be saved into the Selected Images list box", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

        End If


    Else

    End If


    tbSelectCompressImages.TabPages.Add(TabPage2)

    tbSelectCompressImages.SelectedIndex = 1


    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    MsgBox("An error occurred with the Save Images button - " & ex.Message)
    'End Try


End Sub
```

So, I was pretty stumped with that and decided to make a small change to how the bitmap was created to below.  I was able to get 28 images saved again but this time received an out of memory error for the Graphics.FromImage line.

```
    Dim newimage As Bitmap = DirectCast(Image.FromFile(strPath), Bitmap)
```

Does anyone know why this is occurring looking at my code.  Or, is there code somewhere that I can get to set the resolution for an image so that the memory stamp is much smaller?

thanks.

Comment: You are disposing the bejeezus out of everything, but we can't see what you do with sourceImage and outImage.

Comment: I've added the button event that calls this function and yes I was disposing the bejeezus out of everything and will continue to do so if it gets me to yes :).

Comment: Well, I got my code to work.  I had to add System.GC.Collect() to make it work.  I added it to both the button event and SetResolution function.  Anyway, is there someone out here who might now of performance increases with changing and saving the resolution of an image?  It seems like it could go faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but we can't see what you do with sourceImage and outImage.

```
   image1 = SetResolution(image1, 50, strFilePath & "\" & Path.GetFileName(S))
```

You are **re-assigning** the image1 variable with this statement.  Problem is, you never disposed the original image1.  It is also a major guess why you are passing a path name, the method doesn't use it at all.  So somewhat more sane code that doesn't forget to dispose ought to look like this:

```
   Dim newImage = SetResolution(image1, 50)
   image1.Dispose()
   image1 = newImage
```

Comment: Yea the 3rd parameter was when I had a slightly different way of creating the bitmap in the SetResolution function.  I took that out and implemented your changes.  The program still works now using your methodology.  I took out the System.GC.Collect() statements I had in both the button event and function.  Everything works with looping through all my images, resizing and saving over 30 images.